# AirDrop File From App To App But File Only Openable To App

Tags: ios, file-sharing, airdrop

I have an application that airdrops PDFs and is able to handle receiving PDFs. I would like to make it so that only my application is the suggested application for opening the airdropped files from another device containing my application. So send PDF over AirDrop from my app X on device 1 to device 2 also running app X. App X should be the only option to open this PDF.

I have done some research, but to no avail. Does anyone have an example of this, where it can be done programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by having your app define a new file type and then register that your app supports opening it. 
Then when you share the PDF instead share it as the file type you added, which since it's a custom file type your app will be the only one claiming it and therefore the AirDrop transfer will default to your app instead of offering the receiver any app that can open PDFs

Comment: He should also define a format for the file type which only he knows how to process, and possibly encrypt the file. Otherwise if all he's doing is changing the extension, anyone can open the file. And while some operating systems look only at the file extension to determine the type, now-a-days many peek inside the content to determine the type. If iOS changes in future, that would be the case.